# How differ a pointer to first element of a vector vs back_inserter() of that vector?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, adapter

I know `back_inserter` is a container "adapter", but what does it mean? If I take the example of function `std::copy()`, which takes as the third argument output iterator/pointer of vector TO copy, then I should give `back_inserter` instead of `last iterator` of that vector:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> vec1 = {1,2};
    vector<int> vec2 = {3,4};
    copy(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), back_inserter(vec1)); //back_inserter used to enhance memory allocation for 2 new elements?
    for(auto i:vec1){
        printf("%i\n", i);
    }
}
```

*Works fine*, however this version does not:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> vec1 = {1,2};
    vector<int> vec2 = {3,4};
    copy(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), vec1.end()); // the same pointer as gives back_inserter but without any fancy allocation and therefor crash?
    for(auto i:vec1){
        printf("%i\n", i);
    }
}
```

Now I just gave the last iterator/pointer of the vector TO copy. So what is the job of the `back_inserter` container adapter? As it seems for me now, it only does the job of allocation space for new elements, whereas "only" last pointer does not suffice. Can I do a manual job via `malloc` to enlarge that vector/container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The STL is designed with 3 major concepts:

- **containers**

  - hold element(s)
  - know about/create iterators
  - don't know about generic algorithms.
- **iterator**

  - refers to an element (or end), and can modify the elements
  - don't know about algorithms
  - don't know about the container their elements are in* (and thus cannot modify the container in size or otherwise)
- **algorithms**

  - generically work with iterators
  - do *not* know about containers

A **back-inserter**, however, looks and behaves like an iterator, and as far as the algorithms are concerned, it *is* an iterator.  But as a container adapter, it *also* has a reference to the container and can modify it (via "push_back") when you write into its iterator interface.  This allows algorithms to opaquely write into it as an iterator and (without realizing it) also be able to modify the container too.

(*) Occasionally a debugging implementation of iterators will know about containers but that's an internal implementation detail that is not usable by the ordinary public interface.

Comment: Can you please provide a way, how to debug implementation? And a concrete source (implementation) - an example, where the iterators *know* about container? (as in your note (*))

Comment: G++ library has "debug mode"  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode.html), enabled with -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG on the command line.  LLVM standard library does too, enabled with -D_LIBCPP_DEBUG=1 (https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/DesignDocs/DebugMode.html).  MSVC has checked iterators, controlled with macro _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/checked-iterators?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0):

[`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) will copy elements from one iterator range to another iterator range where elements already exist. It does not create new elements.

[`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) will allow the use of `copy` (and other algorithms that require elements to exist) to add elements to an existing container that supports `push_back`.

You could manually expand `vec1` using `resize` before the `copy` to allocate space for the new elements, but that adds complexity that is best avoided (because you have to know how big to resize the vector to, and what iterator to start the copy to).

Answer (score 0):

`back_inserter` takes care of a couple things:

- each time it is written through to store a value (i.e. `*it =`), it grows the `vector` as if you were calling `push_back`; if the `vector`'s `size()` is already equal to its `capacity()`, then that means it will need to allocate a new memory region for the enlarged contents, and copy the existing contents across, before adding the new element
- in being equivalent to `push_back`, it makes sure the `vector`'s `size()` continues to reflect the number of elements stored

The `end()` iterator represents a position one past the end of the currently stored elements, as indicated by `size()`, but the implementation isn't specified. It's undefined behaviour to write through it (i.e. `*vec1.end() = ...`).

> Can I do a manual job via malloc to enlarge that vector/container?

No - vectors are allocated with `new` - not the "C" library function `malloc` - you can't mix the two.  You can however manually increase the memory for the `vector` in two ways:

```
vec1.resize(4);    // then size() == capacity() == 4, [2] and [3] are 0

vec1.reserve(4);   // then size() == 2, capacity() == 4,
                   //      [2] and [3] are unspecified
```

It's undefined behaviour and there's no excuse for actually trying to use it, but for the sake of curiousity: in some implementations, if you'd called `reserve()` as above, `end()` *might* actually be implemented as a pointer to `[2]`, in which case your `copy(..., end())` may coincidentally write to `[2]` and `[3]` as you hoped, but it'd leave the `size()` value at `2` still despite there now being `4` elements stored.  If you'd called `resize(4)` beforehand instead of `reserve()`, so that `size()` would return `4`, then the `copy(..., end())` would have erroneously overwritten the non-existent elements `[4]` and `[5]`.  So, nothing would work properly under any circumstances.